# deleting everything in recyclerview on button click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I added an overflow menu into my app so when the user presses one of the items in the menu called 'delete' all the cardviews they added to the recyclerview are deleted.

I read that I can go something like

```
productList.clear();
```

So I inserted that into my overflow menu code but when I pressed the button nothing happened.

**create.java (main activity)**

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {



    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    Product mProduct;
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();


   // RelativeLayout relativeLayout;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);
        findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout).requestFocus();







        findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });






        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
         CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);

       final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();


        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new Product(mSpinnerItems, "Test Edit Text",false, "Text String 2"));




        final ProductAdapter  adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList, numberItemValues);


        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
             findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                productList.add(mProduct);
                if(adapter != null)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                //Handle the empty adapter here

            }
        });









        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);









    }




    //TODO OVERFLOW MENU
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_delete) {



            ((ProductAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).reset();



            return true;
        }





        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }








    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }



}
```

**productadapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();





   // private SearchableSpinner spinner;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Product> productList;

    private Activity create;


    //TODO CODE FOR CSV FILE


    /*InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
    CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();*/


    InputStream inputStream = null;
    List<String>  mSpinnerItems = null;
    CSVFile csvFile = null;


    //TODO END OF CODE FOR CSV FILE

    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity) {
        create = activity;

    }


    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    /*public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList) {
        // this.mCtx = mCtx;

       *//* inputStream = create.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();*//*

        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }*/


    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList, Map<String, String> numberList) {
        numberItemValues = numberList;
        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(create);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        // //getting the product of the specified position




        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(create, R.layout.item_spinner_layout,
                Product.getSpinnerItemsList());
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int mPosition, long id) {
                mSpinnerSelectedItem.put(position, mPosition);


                TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.mSpinnerText);


                //TODO CODE FOR GETTING AISLE NUMBER AND PUTTING IT IN THE TEXTVIEW
                /*String currentItem = mSpinnerItems.get(position);
                String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                holder.textView5.setText(aisleNumber);

*/




                //String currentItem = holder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String currentItem = holder.spinner.getItemAtPosition(mPosition).toString();

                Set<String> set = numberItemValues.keySet(); for(String key : set) {String value = numberItemValues.get(key); Log.e("DATA ", "key = " + key + " value = " + value); }





                //String currentItem = holder.spinner.getItemAtPosition(mPosition).toString();
                String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                holder.textView5.setText(aisleNumber);

                Log.e("SELECTION TEST", " Selected map item = " + aisleNumber );


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        if (mSpinnerSelectedItem.containsKey(position)) {
            holder.spinner.setSelection(mSpinnerSelectedItem.get(position));
        }


        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create);


                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity


                                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                                holder.spinner.setSelection(0);



                                productList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                                Toast.makeText(create, "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });





    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public void reset() {
        productList.clear();
        notifyDatasetChanged();
    }




    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SearchableSpinner spinner;
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView5;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        View rootView;


        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);


            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.
                    if(isChecked){

                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        spinner.setSelection(0);

                        productList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());



                        Toast.makeText(create, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });



        }

        public View getView() {
            return rootView;
        }

    }






    //TODO CODE FOR CSV FILE
    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you should to clear List and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

upd

Add this into your adapter class

```
 public void reset() { 
   productList.clear(); 
   notifyDataSetChanged(); 
 }
```

if your adapter variable are not declared as class visible variable you could call this function next way

```
((YourAdapterClassName) yourRecyclerView.getAdapter()).reset()
```

in your case it should looks like

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((ProductAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).reset();

            //Handle the empty adapter here
        }
    });
```

Adapter should contain function I wrote before (void reset)

if you would like to add new product into you RecyclerView
you have to create next function

```
public void addNewProduct(Product product){
   productList.add(product);
   notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

and call it same as reset function

your simplified class >>

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {


//we are storing all the products in a list
private List<Object> productList;

public ProductAdapter(Activity activity) {

}


public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Object> productList, Map<String, String> numberList) {
    this.productList = productList;
}

@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflating and returning our view holder
    View view = new View(parent.getContext());
    return new ProductViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}


public void reset() {
    productList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addNewProduct(Object product){
    productList.add(product);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

  class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    View rootView;


    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


    }

    public View getView() {
        return rootView;
    }
  }
}
```